# How to get the id of the element who calls a function in the ngif directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I need to get the id of the element who calls a function inside the ngif directive.

For example, I have this button with the id and the ngif directive:

```html
<button id="buttonId" *ngIf="showId()">BUTTON</button>
```

I need to get the id of this element inside the showId() function

Also, the main reason is not to use the template variable into the function so that this function can automatically get the caller

The idea is to call a service function that knows who the caller is and responds true or false based on who is currently logged in. Since there is a huge refactor to do the idea was not to have the ids as parameters.

Comment: I don't think you can have it anyway when you are using `*ngIf`, unless your `ngIf` returns true, there is no element, hence no id attribute.

Comment: Can you explain what's the idea behind your `*ngIf` relying on the id of the element it has to display (or hide)? I don't really see a valid use case for this.

Answer (score 4):

The very first question, why do you have such a requirement?

Simple and correct way, have variable in your class and use it like:

```
buttonId: string = "buttonId"

<button [id]="buttonId" *ngIf="showId(buttonId)">BUTTON</button>
```

If you want to use `*ngIf` and want to extract the id which is present in the element itself then there is no simple way. Until your `*ngIf` returns true, No element will be created in the DOM, hence no `id` attribute. A bad workaround would be to have a duplicate hidden element like:

```
<button hidden="true" #dupRef id="buttonId">Button</button>
<button id="buttonId" *ngIf="showId(dupRef.id)">BUTTON</button>
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sq8rde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

in Template

```
<button id="buttonId" #btnRef *ngIf="showId(btnRef.id)">BUTTON</button>
```

in Component

```
showId(buttonId){
     console.log(buttonId)
}
```

Comment: This works, but what I want is not to copy each id into the function parameter

Comment: Somehow this will not work. `ngIf` has got to return something only then an element will be created and hence a reference

Comment: Same as before, i don't want any parameters in the "showId()" function.

So I simply can't do this because the element is created after the ngif directive return?

Comment: @ayyylmao If you don't want any parameters then simply use the class variable in the method, use the first approach of my answer and access the class variable in your method like: `showId() { console.log(this.buttonId) ; // return something }`